# My website is getting too many dierect home arechives and this is increasing my bounce rate

Tags: wp-query, security

My website is getting nearly 800 direct home archives daily, as a result the bounce rate of my website has increased. Usually i get only around 30 home archives a day
These hits are not from Google, so how can i stop them.
Actually in my Wordpress Jetpack stats my home archives are going around 800 a day which only used to be around 30 a day, so i think some one is giving fake clicks to my website. So the bounce rate of my website is increasing day by day because these hits are not from any of the search engines and most of these home archives are from india and usa.
So please help me by providing some way out please.

Comment: Please elaborate on what you mean by "direct home archives" - sorry mate, I, at least, do not understand that term. It certainly is not standard WP jargon.

Comment: @JohannesPille bro , i my jetpack views shows my home archives to be around 800 since last few days, these views have no referral, these visitors do not come through any of the search engine. Usually i used to get only 40 home archives and now 800. So how can i stop all these

Comment: please help guys its really important @JohannesPille

Comment: I am still clueless as to what you actually mean. Please explain yourself better. You've attempted to explain the term by repeating it - that doesn't work. If I'd ask you to explain a "red car", you wouldn't say "Well, it's a car that's red." but "Red is a color and a car a 4-wheeled vehicle." See the analogy? And please don't add further info as a comment, but edit your question. That'll also have the advantage of it appearing at the top of the questions queue again.

Comment: @JohannesPille, sorry bro actually i am posting here for the first time so.... and i have edited the ques hope it is more clear now, actually wanted to add a sniped pic of my wordpress jetpack stats but need a reputation more that 10 for that which i dont have

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like google (and/or other search engines) *could* have made an error when indexing your site (but I highly doubt it). You shouldn't have that many hit going to your archive pages.

Recovery steps:

Signup for Google Analytics. Use this to determine where those hit are coming from. (GA is more detailed then JetPack Analytics. I've also seen errors in JP's reportings)

Signup for Google Webmaster Tools. This is so you can see how google is hitting your site and what it's indexing. (you can also request that a page not be indexed)

Find a plugin that can generate a XML site map for search engines. I like http://wordpress.org/plugins/google-sitemap-generator/

Comment: actually analytics is not counting these archive hits, its just showing the actual hits which are around 600 but jetpack is showing 1400 and also some wired referral links @davidkryzaniak

Comment: Who (or which site) is the referrer?